# Feedback in NaiveBayes Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, text-classification

I am a newbie in machine Learning, i am building a complaint categorizer and i want to provide a feedback model so that it can improve over time

```
import numpy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
value=[
'drought',
'robber',
]
targets=[
'water_department',
'police_department',
]
classifier = MultinomialNB()        
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(value)

classifier.partial_fit(counts[:1], targets[:1],classes=numpy.unique(targets))
for c,t in zip(counts[1:],targets[1:]):
    classifier.partial_fit(c, t.split())

value.append('dogs')                                   #new value to train
targets.append('animal_department')                    #new target
vectorize = CountVectorizer()
counts = vectorize.fit_transform(value)
print counts
print targets
print vectorize.vocabulary_
####problem lies here
classifier.partial_fit(counts["""dont know the index of new value"""], targets[-1])
####problem lies here
```

Even if i somehow find the index of newly inserted value, it is giving the error

```
ValueError: Number of features 3 does not match previous data 2.
```

even thought i made it to insert one value at a time

Comment: Do you want to classify single words like 'dogs', 'draught' into target labels (classes) like 'animal', 'water', 'police' etc.? In that case, why not use a dictionary?

Comment: I need to classify sentences that contain these words.

Comment: okay... so in that case... do you have an exhaustive list of words with known labels? i'm not clear of what you're wanting to achieve with the feedback step? this isn't doing a real feedback (user driven)... is that something that you'd want in your application and hence want to simulate it programatically? in summary, you'd want incremental training, if i'm not mistaken?

Comment: Yes, i want incremental training and i want to simulate it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the question from a general point of view. There are two sources of problem in the Naive Bayes (NB) approach described here:

1. Out-of-vocabulary (OOV) problem
2. Incremental training of NB

**OOV problem:** The simplest way to tackle the OOV problem is to decompose every word into character 3 grams. How many such 3-grams are possible? Assuming lower-casing there are only 26 possible ways to fill each place and hence the total number of possible character 3-grams is 26^3=17576, which is significantly lower than the number of possible English words that you're likely to see in text.

Hence, generally speaking, while training NB, a good idea is to use probabilities of character n-grams (n=3,4,5). This will drastically reduce the OOV problem.

**Incremental training:** For incremental training, given a new sentence decompose it into terms (character n-grams). Update the count of of each term for its corresponding observed class label. For example, if *count(t,c)* denotes how many times was the term *t* observed in class *c*, simply update the count if you see *t* in class 0 (or class 1) during incremental training. Updating the counts will update the maximum likelihood probability estimates as well.